# Laravel elastic search not giving contains or like match

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-5, laravel-scout

I wanted to have elasticsearch implemented for all my laravel search queries. I have the latest Laravel and latest elasticsearch installed using brew.

`curl http://localhost:9200/` gives,

```
{
  "name" : "_SFvSGk",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch_an398690",
  "cluster_uuid" : "xBi3aTDaTkmA6dtzhpOrwg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.5.4",
    "build_flavor" : "oss",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "d2ef93d",
    "build_date" : "2018-12-17T21:17:40.758843Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.5.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Here I am using the [driver](https://github.com/babenkoivan/scout-elasticsearch-driver) `babenkoivan/scout-elasticsearch-driver`.

**Model**,

```
namespace App;

use ScoutElastic\Searchable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
    use Searchable;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $indexConfigurator = CustomerIndexConfigurator::class;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $searchRules = [
        CustomerSearchRule::class
    ];

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $mapping = [
        'properties' => [
            'text' => [
                'type' => 'text',
                'fields' => [
                    'ref_num' => [
                        'type' => 'keyword',
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ];
}
```

**SearchRule**,

```
namespace App;

use ScoutElastic\SearchRule;

class CustomerSearchRule extends SearchRule
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function buildHighlightPayload()
    {
        return [
            'fields' => [
                'ref_num' => [
                    'type' => 'plain'
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function buildQueryPayload()
    {
        $query = $this->builder->query;

        return [
                [
                    'match' => [
                        'ref_num' => [
                            'query' => $query,
                            'boost' => 2
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
        ];
    }
}
```

**Configurator**,

```
namespace App;

use ScoutElastic\IndexConfigurator;
use ScoutElastic\Migratable;

class CustomerIndexConfigurator extends IndexConfigurator
{
    use Migratable;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $settings = [
        //
    ];
}
```

I have a record with `ref_num` as `I50263`. So I should get this record when I search `I50` same like `like query`. I tried all the below search but I am getting the result only with the complete word `I50263`.

```
return Customer::search('I50')->get();
// no record
return Customer::search('I50263')->get();
// got record
return Customer::searchRaw([
  'query' => [
     'bool' => [
        'must' => [
            'match' => [
                'ref_num' => 'I502'
            ]
        ]
     ]
  ]
]);
// no record
return Customer::searchRaw([
  'query' => [
      'bool' => [
          'must' => [
             "match_phrase" => [
                "ref_num" => [
                   "query" => "I50",
                   "boost" => 1
                 ]
              ]
           ]
        ]
     ]
 ]);
 // no record
```

Tried field type as `text` also.

Answer (score 1):

As I see, your `ref_num` field is of `keyword` type. Performing [full-text queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/full-text-queries.html) (like `match` or `match_phrase`) does not give you any results. For `keyword`-s you should use [term level queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/term-level-queries.html). Perhaps [prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) would be helpful for you here.

## Example

### Mapping

```
PUT /so54176561
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "ref_num": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Adding sample document

```
POST /so54176561/_doc/1
{
  "ref_num": "I50263"
}
```

### Full-text `match` search on `text` type field

#### by entire value

```
POST /so54176561/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "ref_num": "I50263"
    }
  }
}
```

Result: **document found**

#### by prefix of the value

```
POST /so54176561/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "ref_num": "I50"
    }
  }
}
```

Result: **document not found**

### Term level `prefix` search on `keyword` type field

```
POST /so54176561/_search
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "ref_num.raw": "I50"
    }
  }
}
```

Result: **document found**

As you can see, in the example I used so kind of subfields (`raw` is a subfield of `ref_num` but with a different type). In Elasticsearch it is called `fields` and more about that you can read in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/multi-fields.html).

You can simply use the query with any other query on any other field using [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/query-dsl-bool-query.html) properly.

If you would like to achieve the same result on the `text` type field you have to prepare your index properly. For example, you could use your custom analyzer with an [NGram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) which splits the words into n-gram tokens.

By default, any of the analyzers do not split words so in your case you had only one token in the index:

```
POST /_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "standard",
  "text": "I50263"
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "i50263",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

For full-text search, Elasticsearch is basing on the tokens it has in the index. If tokens do not match the tokens from the search term, then there is no match.

Comment: Can you please elaborate little more here in your answer? What should be the type if I wanted to go for full text search? What if I wanted to match the query in multiple fields like ref_num, name, email?

Comment: Tried the term query but no luck.
`curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "term" : { "ref_num" : "I50263" } 
  }
}'`

Comment: @devo please check my answer again. I described a little bit more.